# is there cryptographically secure hash algorithm/function that allows hashing faster when you concatenate more data?

Tags: function, security, hash, cryptography, cryptographic-hash-function

I need to calculate hash codes for constantly growing dataset and it needs to be cryptographically secure if possible. For example hashing the series of natural numbers, first 1, then 12, then 123.

If cryptographically secure hashing always requires doing everything from the start for each added number, then I need some other hashing. The most secure cryptographically, or something that takes as long as possible to find other data that gives the same hash code.

RAM usage can be massive.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, Cryptographic hash functions work on blocks of sizes like 512-bit,1024 bit or more. What do you want? Hash chaing?

Comment: Yeah, a [(binary) hash chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_chain#Binary_hash_chains) or [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) seems to be the answer.

Comment: Most crypto hashing apis provide a method to obtain a copy of the internal state of the hash object prior to finishing the hash function. This can be used to avoid having to start over when hashing something whose prefix has already been hashed. More details would be helpful to determining what your real use case is.

Comment: Use case is essentially chaining blocks (size can be determined to 512 or multiples of it) with hash values, each block containing two hash values, hash of all the previous data and hash after the data of that block is concatenated. So each block could validate that all the data before that block has not been changed.

Comment: As President Polk suggested above, I think this is possible with any standard cryptographic hash, and you don't need a custom chain construction. (In effect, Merkle-Damgård *is* the chain.) You need a copy of the pre-finalization state of the first hash, and you need all the input that was added in between the first hash and the second. You can then confirm that the first hash is what be you get by finalizing immediately, and the second hash is what you get by adding the new input and then finalizing. You don't need to know the original input, but unfortunately you do need all the new input.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is tree hashing, which is a form of Merkle tree.  Essentially, each data block is hashed, and a hash is computed over the hash of each's data block hash, and so on until you reach the root.  Typically, there are dedicated designs for this that prevent the security problems with the immediate and naïve approach.

If you'd like to incrementally append more data, then you'll obviously need to store the hashes for the data blocks or at least some intermediate values so you can recompute the root hash efficiently.  BLAKE2 has a special tree mode which can be used, although I'm not sure if any of the standard libraries support it, so you may need to take the reference code and configure it accordingly.  BLAKE2 is cryptographically secure and extremely fast, even in plain C.

There's also the newer BLAKE3, which is supposed to be cryptographically secure and is even faster.  It always runs in a tree hash mode.  However, it has seen less cryptanalysis than BLAKE2, and so I would recommend BLAKE2 for almost all applications.

There are similar approaches for other hash functions, but these are the fastest cryptogpaphically secure options.

Comment: This could be done with stock BLAKE3, but the feature hasn't been implemented anywhere to my knowledge. Something similar was requested here: https://github.com/oconnor663/bao/issues/35. The summary is "given two root hashes of a growing file at different times, produce a log-size proof that the earlier hash is indeed a prefix of the latter one". It's quite a specialized thing to want to do, and it would take a good bit of recursive fanciness, but it is doable.